# Changing page layout

Tags: page-layout

Is it possible to revert or bring back the old page layout, post changed in sps2013?

Also, changing page layout does that impacts the webparts already placed on the homepage?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can revert your page layout using SharePoint Designer.

Open your site in SharePoint designer and go to Page Layouts section select your page layout go to version history of that page layout select the respective version and revert it back.

Yes changing the page layout will impact the webparts.

Comment: If the page layout has been changed to a new layout. Will it allow to revert the the old page layout using SPD 2013?

Comment: No you can not revert the page layout using SPD 2013.

Comment: Any other suggestion, to combat my issue of reverting the earlier page layout?